# How to send a Font File to a Zebra Printer (MZ 220) via .Net SDK?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, zebra-printers

I have to send custom Font Files to a Zebra MZ 220 Printer via C# and the Zebra .Net SDK. That SDK provides a SendFile() Method and it works with template Files percectly but whenever I send a Font File the printer starts printing out the File while receiving it.
The Zebra Software Label Vista has a Menu option Send Font but I have to do ist programmatically.

Does anyone know how to send Font Files to the Printer?

Thank you very much

twickl

Comment: Are these font files already encoded in a Zebra format, or are they Truetype or some other Windows format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap the file in a special download command in order for the printer to store the file.

The command is detailed in the [ZPL Guide](http://zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/documentlibrary/manuals/en/zpl_II_program_guide_en.File.tmp/P1012728-002e.pdf?dvar1=ProductLiterature&dvar2=Programming%20Guide%20(for%20ZPL%20II,%20ZPI%202,%20Set-Get-Do,%20Mirror,%20WML)%20(en)%20&dvar3=48) under "CISDFCRC16".

Basic format for the command -

```
! CISDFCRC16
<crc>          // 4 digit hex CRC.  Enter 0000 to turn off CRC check.
<filename>     // file name with extension.  8.3 filenames only.
<size>         // eight digit hex file size in bytes.
<checksum>     // four digit hex checksum.  Enter 0000 to turn off checksum validation.
<data>         // Binary data to store
```

This will allow you to store a file on the printer's file system.

Note:  The printer will not understand a typical .ttf file.  You will need to convert the font to a .CPF file using Label Vista, and then send it down using this command.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with LP 2824 to automatically print labels with EPL and used the [RawPrinterHelper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) class from Microsoft, with the bug fix from [here](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c/). The class has a SendFileToPrinter method which might be worth a try (I haven't used it, so I don't know if it works for fonts)

Comment: I wanted to add these archive links for anyone that stumbles into this thread as both are dead now. MS redesigned killed many of their kb articles, either gone completely or no redirect! Bad form. The other site is just dead.

[MS RawPrinter code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363847/c-sharp-rawprinterhelper-sends-data-to-printer-printer-spools-and-states-print).

[This is the article with the bugfix](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326001357/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c/).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to James's answer. He is indeed correct the '! CISDFCRC16' call does work.

I initially was having a lot of trouble getting it to work however because I implementing my own CRC and Checksum logic.

When uploading the file to the printer I was always getting a 'Checksum failed' message come out of the printer. Even after implementing the CRC/Checksum logic given to us in the CPCL programming manual.

The only way I managed to get this to work was by using Zebra's CpclCrcHeader class to calculate the CRC using the **CpclCrcHeader.getCRC16ForCertificateFilesOnly(byteArray).toUpperCase()** and the Checksum using the **CpclCrcHeader.getWCheckSum(byteArray).toUpperCase()**

Hope that helps anyone else wanting to manage all the files on their Zebra printers.