# c# RawPrinterHelper sends data to printer, printer spools and states "printed" but doesnt actually print

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am using the RawPrinterHelper class as described here:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c-.net

I am using the code exactly as per the example and it appeared to work immediately with no errors - except that it didnt actually print.

Inspected the print queue shows the print job appearing, and immediately disappearing. If I change the properties to keep old prints I can see that it classes the job as "Printed". However nothing has actually printed!

I have tried printing directly to the printers using Notepad, Word and excel and all were successful. I have tried 3 different printers, and even re-done the work on a different machine with a different printer but still have the same issue.

I am using Windows 10 professional, and VS2017.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Allow the user to select a file.
       OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (DialogResult.OK == ofd.ShowDialog(this))
        {
            // Allow the user to select a printer.
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
            {
                // Print the file to the printer.
                RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, ofd.FileName);
            }
        }
    //other tests - these both return True and the job appears in print queue as "printed"
       // label1.Text = RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter("Citizen CL-S521", @"C:\Development\Code\myText.txt").ToString();

        //label2.Text = RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("Citizen CL-S521F", "Test string").ToString();
    }

    public class RawPrinterHelper
    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "RAW Document";
            // Win7
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Win8+
            // di.pDataType = "XPS_PASS";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            fs = null;
            return bSuccess;
        }
        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            dwCount = szString.Length;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: On windows 10 the drivers have been updated so the provided code no longer works. [Try this](https://github.com/tonyedgecombe/RawPrint) and hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately this does exactly the same (across different printers and different machines) - sends to printer - says "Printing" then "Printed" but doesnt actually print anything!

Comment: @DavidWhiteford did you have some advance on this? I'm. having the same problem: SATO tthermal label printer, SBL language, using RawPrinterHelper, it is not working